# How to write an index in objectify, which returns the newest results first?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have an index entity with the following fields:

```
@Index private String entry;
@Index private Date created;
// ...
```

When the index is queried, the first letters of the search term (here: find) are compared against the entry:

```
Key<Result> fromKey = Key.create(Result.class, find);
Key<Result> toKey = Key.create(Result.class, find + "\uFFFD");
query = query.filterKey(">=", fromKey).filterKey("<", toKey);
```

[Note that in this case the entry is appended and used as the key, but it should not change anything in this regard.]

This returns all entities where entry starts with the searched term. So far, fine.

Now I want the results sorted by "created" date, but the app store doesn't let me do this:

```
query = query.order("-created");
```

It returns "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The first sort property must be the same as the property to which the inequality filter is applied."

I cannot do the sort in code, because I need to do paging, where I always query the next page of results dependent on the "created" date: Client queries the first page, then sends the same query with the date of the last result to receive the second page, etc.

Essentially, I think it comes down to the problem that we have two inequality filters involved here, which datastore does not support.

Is there a way to efficiently solve this problem? How do you write an index? Do you use full-text search instead? Or is there a way to solve this in datastore/objectify, like circumventing this using a composite index of multiple fields?

--

The only weird solution that I came up with is creating multiple fields within the index record or adding the record multiple times. Example:

entry = "hotel" -> add as "h", "ho", "hot", "hote" and "hotel"

Not very efficient, but that would make the inequality search an equality search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implement search-as-you-type using an indexed multi-property field populated with every fragment that "hits", similar to your "weird solution". The search query is an equality filter, plus an inequality filter on another field for sort ordering. This has the benefit of satisfying the 'advanced indexing' queries described here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection

...thus you can filter on the field multiple times if the user types in multiple fragments.

The equality queries are very efficient; the only downside is extra storage and indexing. Whether or not this is a problem depends on how many rows and how many fragments you're storing (and your budget).

FWIW, all Lucene-based text search engines (Elasticsearch, Solr, etc) work pretty much just like this - they index a reverse mapping from analyzed token to document. In fact, you can use the Lucene analyzers every effectively to create your indexed fragments. Just make sure you analyze the query terms as well as the stored data.

Comment: The multi-property field is smarter than using multiple fields I guess [I didn't know this exists], but I assume the index still stores each of the values as a separate item. How can I set a multi-property field in objectify? Just use a collection as Google describes it for the native datastore?

Comment: @Index private List<String> entries; entries = new ArrayList<String>();
        entries.add(entry.substring(0, 3));
        entries.add(entry.substring(0, 4));
        entries.add(entry.substring(0, 6));
        entries.add(entry.substring(0, 9)); unformatted, sorry, but would this work?

Comment: An INDEXED MULTI-PROPERTY FIELD is the solution. Works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I saw in one of google's IO explaining the datastore (if only I could remember which -_-) that they force you to use your inequality filter as your first sort order because of how the data is indexed for query. Using it another way would force server-side computations, something the datastore is unable to do.

In these cases normally I do sort within the app itself, which, as you pointed out is not a solution for you.  So either using different tables for different dates and querying the "correct tables" only, or using a "hack" with your string searched, would be the only feasible way I can think of to bypass your problem. If something else comes to mind I will edit this, but I don't see any other way so far.